# Central limit theorem in Bagging

Tags: machine-learning, references, central-limit-theorem, bagging

I am in process of trying to understand the statistical theory behind Machine learning. I came across the fact that central limit theorem plays a key role in the Bagging algorithm (in ML). I searched for it online and found some interesting links, but didn't have much success in finding something concrete, which explains this phenomenon in depth. Any pointers or explanation with an example in this regard would be highly appreciated.